# How can I capture the stdout/stderr from exec instead of popen?

Tags: python

I want to create a Python program that takes in another Python file as an argument, executes it and processes the the stdout/stderr while still returning stdout/stderr to the calling processes. Basically, these two should be equivalent from the end user's point of view (though the first is doing some extra processing the user doesn't see)

```
python passthrough.py some_example.py
```

vs

```
python some_example.py
```

I've seen examples of how to do this using popen and pipes, but for other reasons I can't do this in a subprocess; it needs to use the same interprete, so I need to use exec. Is it still possible to do this? To be more clear, I want passthrough.py to behave like this:

```
def process_output(text):
    pass
def process_err(text):
    pass

file_to_run = sys.argv[1]
sys.stdout = sys.stdout && process_output  # pipe stdout to sys.stdout AND some func
sys.stderr = sys.stderr && process_err # pipe stderr to sys.stdout AND some func
execfile(file_to_run) # Would actually use exec so it works with 3.x as well
```

Comment: In cpython, `sys.executable` is the path to the current executable. Doesn't work for embedded python, but may work for you.

Comment: You might look at `itertools.tee` to split each stream, assigning one of the two children back to `sys.whatever` and passing the other to `process_whatever`.